# NetSuite Unexplained Error : "An unexpected SuiteScript error has occurred"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to understand why ever time I save a particular custom record type, I get an error screen saying "An unexpected SuiteScript error has occurred", and nothing else. It started happening suddenly. I turned off all known applicable scripts and workflows. There's nothing recorded in script logs, and the message doesn't even point to anything. I can delete a record just fine, and I seem to be able to create records just fine. But it doesn't seem to allow some editing. Here's a general operation breakdown:

- DELETE ===> success, no error
- CREATE ===> success, error
- EDIT ===> failure, error
- XEDIT ===> success, error

I'd disable every script and workflow in the system, but there are too many, and a total of only 6 were set to be applied to the record type. I've pretty much exhausted what I know to look for, so if anyone knows anything else I could check, that would be appreciated.

[image: error screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Scripted Records" in the search bar. In the "scripts" drop-down menu, select "all". Now you can filter on the "record" column, click on any script that applies to your custom record. Here you will see all scripts that relate to your custom record. Check in the "status" column for any "Released" scripts.

Comment: I've already done that, didn't find anything that I didn't already know about.

Comment: You mentioned that only 6 scripts run on you specific record type. If you disable these one by one and see if the error still occurs, you could determine which script is causing the error.

Comment: Again, that's the process I used. Turning them on and off, one at a time, trying to see which it was. When that didn't yield positive results, I turned them all off at the same time. That also did not yield positive results. The next morning the issue was gone, so I am unsure as to what was actually the problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue on NetSuite's side. I have been having a few issues myself lately with processes that don't do what they normally do, especially with regards to emailing files from NetSuite. At least your problem seems to be fixed now.